# C# ToTitleCase and text-formatted dates/times

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I have a string "THURSDAY 26th JANUARY 2011".

When I format this using CultureInfo.ToTitleCase():

```
var dateString = "THURSDAY 26th JANUARY 2011";
var titleString = myCultureInfoObject.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dateString);
```

It is displayed like this: `"Thursday 26Th January 2011"`. This is exactly what I need...except the *T* in **26Th** has been capitalised. Is there any way to stop this from happening as it is a date and looks wrong? I.e only title-casing characters that don't have a number directly before them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a regex with a `MatchEvaluator` to put only "real" words in title case:

```
var dateString = "THURSDAY 26th JANUARY 2011";
MatchEvaluator ev = m => myCultureInfoObject.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(m.Value);
var titleString = Regex.Replace(dateString, @"\b[a-zA-Z]+\b", ev);
```

This will apply title case only to "THURSDAY" and "JANUARY", but not "26TH" because it doesn't match the regex pattern.

Comment: +1 - nice....but what is it they say about solving a problem with regular expressions?  Now you have two problems.  :)